# Room Migration Alter Table not adding new column & migrate getting called again and again

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

So basically i am using room and trying to add migration from database version 1 to 2 but my alter command is not working 
My current implementation is below :

```
 void init() {
    db = Room.databaseBuilder(Global.getInstance(),
            AppDatabase.class, "feed").addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build();
}
```

Migration property :

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1,2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {


        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'post' ADD COLUMN 'age' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0");
        Log.d("VROM","Migration");
    }
};
```

Database implementation :

```
@Database(entities = {Feed.class, DownloadModel.class}, version = 1) public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public abstract DaoAccess getFeedDao();}
```

So after incrementing the version from 1 to 2, the `execSQL()` is executed but new column is not added in my db. 
I have pulled my db from app directory and checked multiple times but column is not there. Apart from that if I kill my app and launch it again the `migrate` method is called again , don't know if this is the intended functionality but it breaks the functionality for me.I thought migrate will be only called once same as `onUpgrade()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure your column is in model class. In your case, you are adding column `age` like this: `ADD COLUMN 'age' INTEGER`, so you must have `int age` in your model class.

Also, it is a good idea to write migration test to known exactly what is failing. You can find about migration test in android documentation here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#db-migration-testing

Comment: i have accepted the answer, but it  partially solved my problem. I will update my answer and add what exactly solved for me

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing version=2 in AppDatabase inside @Database.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I had the same problem and things that might also help are:

1. A newly added field needs a **default value**. If you add a new field, it must have a certain value for old elements in the database. This can be a specific value (e.g. `0` for an `Int` type) or simply `null` if the field is nullable.

or

2. Making changes int the model and starting the application will generate a **new `.json` file with the new(!) schema**. So you have a new `.json` file, with new changes but with the old version (schema) number.

   Remember to make changes in the following order:

   - increasing the database schema version (field `version` in `@Database(...)`)
   - introducing changes to the data model (`@Entity`)
   - launching the application

   If you have overwritten the old schema file, simply roll back (revert) the changes, upgrade the database version and generate a new schema. You will then have two `json` files. Old as it should be, and new with a new field (to be added by automigration).