# Android room migration code executing multiple times

Tags: android, android-room

We are migrating from AppVersion 2.3 to AppVersion 2.4. `Till 2.3 we had used GreenDao. In 2.4 we have used Room.` We have written migration code for DB changes in Room. Now problem is that `migration code is executing multiple times`.

Comment: it will happen only if your migration is not successful due to any issues. The Migration code will execute every time unless it succeeds.

Comment: Have you faced any issues like this before. Because we are unable to identify what is causing this issue. We have written all migrations.

Comment: yes, I faced a similar situation. I was using room and migration was not getting successful but there were no errors. Even the test case was showing migration was successful but it wasn't. I asked a similar question a year back. You can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687160/room-migration-alter-table-not-adding-new-column-migrate-getting-called-again

Comment: Thanks @Gautam. Whatever is said in that post we have already taken care that. We have it migration code also and even in model class.

Comment: In that post, only part of the problem was solved but what actually solved for me as we were having two entities having the same model/pojo & during migration I was only updating my single entity. Hope it gives you an idea what else can be a problem.Might not be exactly same.